# Traverse Sorting in alphabetical order, print one by one and number of unique books

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

My first class:

```
public class Book 
{
private int id;
private String author, title;

public Book(int id, String author, String title)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
}

 public int getId()
{
   return id;
}
public String getAuthor()
{
   return author;
}
public String getTitle()
{
   return title;
}

public void setId(int setID)
{
    this.id = setID;
}
public void setAuthor(String setAuthor)
{
    this.author = setAuthor;
}
public void setTitle(String setTitle)
{
    this.author = setTitle;
}

public String toString()
{
    String info = "\tID: " + id + "\tAuthor: " + author + "\tTitle: " + title +"\n";
    return info;
}
}
```

My 2nd class:

```
public class BookShelf 
{ 

private Book books;

ArrayList<Book> listOfBooks  = new ArrayList<Book>();

public void addBook(Book addBook)
{
    listOfBooks.add(addBook);
}

public ArrayList<Book> returnListOfBooks()
{


    return listOfBooks;
}

public ArrayList<Book> returnListOfBooksByAuthor(String requestAuthor)
{
    String author = books.getAuthor();
    ArrayList<Book> authorList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Book b: listOfBooks)
    {
        if(author.equals(requestAuthor))
        {
            authorList.add(b);
        }
    }
    return authorList;
}
}
```

My drvier class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookShelfApp 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<>();
   BookShelf shelf = new BookShelf();

   Scanner Id = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner Author = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner Title = new Scanner(System.in);

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       System.out.print("Enter the ID of book:");
       int id = Id.nextInt();

       System.out.print("Enter the author of book:");
       String author = Author.nextLine();

       System.out.print("Enter the title of book:");
       String title = Title.nextLine();

       Book books = new Book(id, author, title);
       shelf.addBook(books);

   }
   System.out.println(shelf.listOfBooks);
}

}
```

I manage to call method to return the list of books from the bookshelf. What i dont know how to traverse in a array and print it out by sorting by title in alphabetical order

And last, call method to return the list of books by author from BookShelf object, traverse list of books one by one and list number of unique books

Hope you can help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sort` method from `Collections` class like:

```
Collections.sort(shelf.returnListOfBooks(), new Comparator<Book>() {
public int compare(Book thisBook, Book thatBook) {
     return String.compareTo(thisBook.getTitle(), thatBook.getTitle());
}
});
```

To traverse over the list, you need a for loop like:

```
for (Book book : shelf.returnListOfBooks()) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Do i put that in the class of bookshelf since i need to sort it out in that class bookshelf? Or do you have a simpler code to tell me so i can understand better?